How to read a 2D Aztec barcode in react-native directly from a file?
I want to select an image from the gallery, in react-native, and read it's content with an Aztec scanner directly, not needing to use the camera and such. For the imgPicker I'm using 'expo-image-picker'. That returns an URI to cached copy of the file. Mostly interested in getting it working in Android.
I looked up to ZXing-js but, if i'm not mistaken, it depends on browser only API's like Canvas and such.
One option that comes to mind is to directly bind it from the Java library, but there is really no other option out there?
